# Testing for the presence of a named capture group

Tags: java, regex

I have a chunk of code that is pulling dates out of strings based on a regex supplied by the user. There are several different ways of configuring the system but generally the most  convenient for the user is to just specify a named capture group which the code then extracts a date from. For example:

```
Input: ABC-20130308
Regex: ABC-(?<date>\d{8})
```

The code is really simple:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( regex );
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
m.find();
m.group( "date" );
```

The problem is that when the user doesn't specify a named group `m.group("date")` blows up with an IllegalArguementException.

I can quite easily catch this exception and try alternative methods for getting a date but that's basically using exceptions for flow of control. I'd much rather test for the presence of the group before I try to get it. Have I missed some way of checking for the presence of a named group in a pattern?

Comment: The MatchResult Interface which is implemented from Matcher has no group Method which excepts a String -> IllegalArgument Exception. It seems as if you can't use the name from the Java Interface. You must use the position of the group.

Comment: In your example this would be m.group(1). It's not the answer of your question but a possible workaround. In complex regular expressions it would be nice to use the groups name and not the position. But it looks like, you could use the name only for references within the expression itself.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you but you can call the group( String ) method from inside code quite easily as long as you are using Java 7 or later.

Comment: My own regex tester (I read the specification of the named group in the documentation, so the regex to pick out named group should be correct) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5115802

Comment: @wobblycogs Your right, i looked only into the 1.6 Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`java.util.regex.Matcher.group(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28java.lang.String%29) throws an

> IllegalArgumentException - If there is no capturing group in the pattern with the given name

So perhaps you could use [`groupCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount%28%29) to do a basic check. But I fear you must handle the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I've coded it up to handle the exception. The groupCount idea might have worked but it would be awkward and very error prone if ever I expanded the system to grab other data from the text. Feels like there's a bit of missing API.

Answer (score 0):

How about running a regexp match on the pattern (supplied by the user, and handled as a plain String at first) that checks whether the group name was included?

e.g. `.*\(?<date>.+\).*` or similar.

Comment: I really like this idea but unfortunately it's not going to work in my situation - it's complicated but boils down to the fact that the group might not be called "date", that's just the default name and the pattern is actually already compiled by the time I get to the "interesting" code.

Comment: @wobblycogs class `Pattern`: `public String pattern()` Returns the regular expression from which this pattern was compiled. Obviously you don't need to hardcode the part of the string that corresponds to the group name either.

Comment: @wobblycogs on second thought, you can always **extract** the group name from the supplied Pattern, e.g. `.*\(?<(.+)>.+\).*`.

Comment: @fr13dwin: Your thought is on the right track, but your regex is not going to work in general case.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I see - escapes and all that :-S . Well, there's the general idea, I'm sure wobblycogs can refine the regex until it works right in his circumstances. Or simply work with numbered groups, as named groups still work on numbers too....

Comment: @fr13dwin: The biggest problem is greedy quantifier. Other than that, it should work. You can see my comment to his question. (I don't attempt to extract correctly, since there is also the mess with `\Q` and `\E`. I only extract candidates).